# Weirdness when using 3d transitions

Tags: css, 3d, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to make sort of flip effect using CSS3.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/MNhK7/

There is one problem though, as you can see in Chrome 19 or FF 11 the element is displaced during the transition but the end and start position is as it should be, why?

I've set `transform-origin` which I thought was supposed to prevent this from happening, what am I missing?

Comment: +1 You just made me waste a click (and now this comment) so I thought about doing another two clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, I of course had to specify a `transform-origin` initially that's the same or it's animated from `50% 50%`